# use dplyr case_when programmatically

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use dplyr case_when and pass variable but the result was not as expected.

Example:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cg = case_when(carb <= 2 ~ "low",
                        carb > 2  ~ "high")) ---this works
```

However, when I try to pass a variable, it returns all as "low"

```
var <- quo(carb)
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cg = case_when(!!var <= 2 ~ "low",
                    !!var > 2  ~ "high"))
```

Comment: the code you propose works for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an order of operations problem, you need to use brackets:

```
quo_function <- function(df, var) {
  df %>%
    mutate(cg = case_when((!!var) <= 2 ~ "low",
                          (!!var) > 2 ~ "high"))  
}
```

Have a look at this post [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062424/great-than-sign-and-quosure-producing-error).

Comment: The best I can tell is that the (!!var) can be replace with just var.